# How to list all registry keys and their subkeys names using Win API (C++)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm aware of the functions like RegOpenKey, RegGetValue and etc. But I can't figure out how to get all keys and their subkeys names. How can I do such thing?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [RegEnumKeyEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regenumkeyexw) and to get the values, [RegEnumValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regenumvaluew).

Comment: Also, related: [`RegQueryInfoKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryinfokeyw)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry. Following a few links in RegOpenKey ,you'll land there.